# Three20 TTTableViewController reload data

Tags: objective-c, three20

How can I reload the data in the TTTableViewController? I tried to 
call reloadData but it doesn't display the new data. 
I have created the datasource file, which is a subclass of 
TTListDataSource. Basically, the init function looks like this.

```
- (id) initWithObject:(NSArray *)objects { 
        if (self = [super init]) { 
                NSMutableArray *priceItems = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init]  autorelease]; 
                for (int i = 0; i < [objects count]; i++) { 
                        [priceItems addObject: 
                         [PriceItem itemWithName: 
                                [[objects objectAtIndex:i] objectAtIndex:0] 
                                          lastDone:[[objects objectAtIndex:i] objectAtIndex:1] change:[[objects objectAtIndex:i] objectAtIndex:2]]];                                                                                           
                } 
                self.items = [NSArray arrayWithArray:priceItems]; 
        } 
        return self;  }
```

After the view is loaded, i start to streaming some data, thus the 
objects passed to initWithObject is changed, so I call 'reload' in the 
subclass of the TTTableViewController in order to update the data, but 
the data is not updated. It doesn't work for refresh method too. Do I need to implement any other method in 
the subclass of TTListDataSource?

Comment: did you find the answer for this question?

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
[self invalidateModel];
```

That should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

**invalidateModel** will rebuild the model, that's not efficient.

Try **[TTTableViewController refresh]**, your table will be reloaded.